# Vue reactive forms components communication

Tags: forms, vuejs2, components, communication

I have multiple form components, each form as a component. Now, I want to use same component for adding data and editing data. So what I am thinking to do is something like when the Post component receives a prop containing data that means it is in a "editing mode" and populate the fields with its data, if not it is in "create mode".
So how should I use v-model in my form fields?

Should I v-model each form field to a computed property (which has a getter and a setter) and the computed property would check if the data prop is empty and if not use its data to populate fields ? And in the computed property set method to update the prop ?

parent component

```
<post :data.sync="dataObject"></post>
```

child (Post) component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" label="title" v-model="computedTitle" />
      <input type="text" label="message" v-model="computedMessage" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <input type="button" @click="submitted"
<template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
       post:{
         title:null,
         message:null
       }
    }
   },
  props:["data"],
  computed:{
     computedTitle:{
          get(){
             return data ? data.title : ''
          },
          set(computedTitle){
             computedTitle = computedTitle // trying to update computed property value with the field value...
          }
     },
     computedMessage:{...}
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: or should I v-model with my data() and watch for data prop and if it is not empty to assign its values to data() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `watch` to check `data` prop, if it's set then set to local `post` variable.

- If created, then `data` is null, `post.title` and `post.message` are set to null
- If updated, then `data` is not null, `post.title` is set to `data.title` and `post.message` to set to `data.message`

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <form>
          <input type="text" label="title" v-model="post.title" />
          <input type="text" label="message" v-model="post.message" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <input type="button" @click="submitted"
    <template>

    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return{
           post: {
             title: null,
             message: null
           }
        }
       },
      props:["data"],
      watch: {
        data: {
          handler(newData) {
            if (newData) {
              this.post = {
                title: newData.title,
                message: newData.message
              }
            }
          },
          immediate: true // this makes watch is called when component created
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Note that you should use `immediate: true` to make the watch's function called when component is created

Comment: what I actually did is on created() if a prop is passed set the local data() accordingly.   So the fields in the child components are linked with v-model like "nothing happened" :) Thanks for your reply.